# getting Null value while getting data from another activity 

Tags: android, android-intent

HI i am getting null pointer exception while sending image path to another activity

here is below my code

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        System.out.println(requestCode + ",      " + resultCode);
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

            if (data.getData() != null) {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    String path = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                    System.out.println("PATH  =  "+path);
                    Intent _intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AndroidFaceDetector.class);
                    _intent.putExtra("mypath", path);
                    startActivityForResult(_intent, CROPPED_FACE_IMAGE);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            setImage(data);
        }

    }
}
```

Now in AndroidFaceDetector class

```
     @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new myView(this));
    Intent _intent = getIntent();
    path = _intent.getStringExtra("mypath");
    System.out.println("Path is gettting "+path); //here i am getting null value
}
```

because

here i am getting path value null.. can any body solve this problem....

Comment: @Siddhpura Amit Did you find any solution? Got stuck in same situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  like this in Second Activity

```
        Intent myintent = getIntent();
        if(null != myintent.getExtras())
        {
              // do your work here 
        String path = myintent.getExtras().getString("mypath");          
        }
        else
        {
              // not here you can't get values
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Recor Here..",12).show();    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second activity try with this code instead of yours,

```
path = _intent.getString("mypath");
```

(or)

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String pic = bundle.getString("mypath");
```

If you wish to pass image instead of URI means try this code

In your First activity,

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(AndroidPassingBitmap.this, AndroidReceiveBitmap.class);
        intent.putExtra("Bitmap", bitmap);
        startActivity(intent);
```

In your Second activity,

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Bitmap");
  ImageView viewBitmap = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bitmapview);

  viewBitmap.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: ya i have tried like this way also but do not no why i am getting null value

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit: in your first activity the path having values?

Answer (score 0):

Write below Code to get data from intent, it will solve your problem.

```
Bundle bdl=getIntent().getExtras();
String path=bdl.getString("mypath");
```

And see below link for more information.

[pass bitmap between activities in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720589/can-not-pass-bitmap-between-activities-in-android/11720640#11720640)