# Intent in Checkbox to send Bitmap to GridView doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, android-gridview

I am trying to send a bitmap that I make during a onCheck method of a checkbox over to a gridView where the bitmap would then show up in the gridView. I'm trying to convert the bitmap to a byte array and then pass that array to an intent where I would then set the bitmap up in my other activity (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720589/can-not-pass-bitmap-between-activities-in-android)) but I can't get the intent to work.

Here is my onClick method of my checkbox:

```
        addCheckbox
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    if (addCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                        System.out.println("Checked");
                        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
                        Drawable icon = null;
                        try {
                            icon = pm
                                    .getApplicationIcon(entry.packageName);
                        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Drawable default_icon = pm.getDefaultActivityIcon();
                        if (icon instanceof BitmapDrawable
                                && default_icon instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                            BitmapDrawable icon_bd = (BitmapDrawable) icon;
                            Bitmap icon_b = icon_bd.getBitmap();
                            BitmapDrawable default_bd = (BitmapDrawable) pm
                                    .getDefaultActivityIcon();
                            Bitmap default_b = default_bd.getBitmap();
                            if (icon_b == default_b) {
                                // It's the default icon

                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                default_b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(this, GridView.class);
                                intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Un-Checked");
                    }

                }
```

Then I am trying to set it up in my GridView class:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class GridView extends Activity implements OnItemLongClickListener, OnDragListener{

ArrayList<Integer> drawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();

private BaseAdapter adapter;
private int draggedIndex = -1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drag_and_drop_app);
    drawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern1);
    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern2);
    android.widget.GridView gridView = (android.widget.GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter = new BaseAdapter() {

        @Override
        // Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in
        // the data set.
        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup gridView) {
            // try to reuse the views.
            ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
            // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse
            // it
            if (view == null) {
                view = new ImageView(GridView.this);
            }
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

            Bitmap default_b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

            view.setImageBitmap(default_b);
            view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
            view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
            view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        // Get the row id associated with the specified position in the
        // list.
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        // Get the data item associated with the specified position in the
        // data set.
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return drawables.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        // How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter.
        public int getCount() {
            return drawables.size();
        }
    });
}
```

Am I going about this the right way? If so, how can I fix my intent to work with the onCheck method? If not, what can I do to change it? I've looked around stackoverflow for a while and this was really the only solution that I've seen (converting to byte array and things) but I've never seen it with a checkbox.

Comment: Why don't you pass name of the bitmap (here drawable) and fetch bitmap in next activity, that will work for you. Why are you doing all the processing here, which should be part of your next activity?

Comment: @BetteDevine So I am passing the bitmap over from the checkbox after creating the bitmap in one activity over to my gridView activity, which handles everything for the gridView (i.e. just setting up the image from the checkbox in an imageView). (I hope that's what your asking, if not let me know) Can you explain what you mean by passing over the name of the bitmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to change from a compound button to a simple onClickListener. It still works the same and can support the intent better.