# how to pass images through intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

**First class**

```
public class ChooseDriver extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

  private static final String rssFeed   = "http://trade2rise.com/project/seattle/windex.php?itfpage=driver_list";  
  private static final String ARRAY_NAME = "itfdata";
  private static final String ID = "id";
  private static final String NAME = "name";
  private static final String IMAGE = "image";

  List<Item> arrayOfList;
  ListView listView;
  MyAdapter objAdapter1;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.choose_driver);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Item item = (Item) objAdapter1.getItem(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseDriver.this, DriverDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra(ID, item.getId());
        intent.putExtra(NAME, item.getName().toString());
        // intent.putExtra(IMAGE, item.getImage().toString());        
        // image.buildDrawingCache();
        // Bitmap image= image.getDrawingCache();
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        // extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", image);
        intent.putExtras(extras);

        startActivity(intent); 
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Second class**

```
public class DriverDetail extends Activity {

  private ImageLoader imageLoader;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.driver_detail);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDname);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("imagebitmap");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp );
    //imageView.set(getIntent().getExtras().getString("image"));
    tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"));
  } 
}
```

By using it I can show text very well, but I can't show an image on second Aactivity.

Comment: i think you have just pass image path as string and try to load image from this path on other activity.

Comment: you never pass image you just play with their path

Comment: Have you used this  extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", image);?

Comment: how to pass image through the path?I am a new user.please help me..

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do you pass images (bitmaps) between android activities using bundles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352172/how-do-you-pass-images-bitmaps-between-android-activities-using-bundles)

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/q/4352172 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12908048 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/11720640